# Invert order of Meter with left repeat bar

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to invert the order of Meter with left repeat bar, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}


\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}4}
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás
    \leftrepeat\Notes\zcharnote{g}{\hspace*{-2.8cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 24}}}\zcharnote{n}{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \huge{\A\bfseries\large 1}}\isluru0l\qu f\qu e\qu f\tslur0k\qu e\en\rightrepeat%\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOTes\hu f\hp\en\leftrepeat
    %3er compás
    \Notes\zcharnote{n}{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \huge{\A\bfseries\large 2}}\isluru0k\qu e\qu d\qu e\tslur0j\qu d\en\rightrepeat
    %4to compás
    \NOTes\hu e\hp\en\leftrepeat
    %5to compás
    \Notes\zcharnote{n}{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \huge{\A\bfseries\large 3}}\islurd0d\qu d\qu c\qu d\tslur0c\qu c\en\rightrepeat
    %6to compás
    \NOTes\hu d\hp\en
    %\setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: As a musician I would advise you not to imitate weird notation. The general meter has to be placed outside the repetition. If you want to produce your desired output, you should not use \generalmeter, but a \meterfrac after the leftrepeat, like you placed the meters in your question about different meters in two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!!! The output is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
\usepackage{colortbl} %Color a tablas
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}


\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    %\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}4}
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás
    \leftrepeat
    \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}\zchangecontext
    \Notes\zcharnote{g}{\hspace*{-3.1cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 24}}}\zcharnote{n}{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \huge{\A\bfseries\large 1}}\isluru0l\qu f\qu e\qu f\tslur0k\qu e\en\rightrepeat%\bar
    %\Notes\isluru0l\qu f\qu e\qu f\tslur0k\qu e\en\rightrepeat%\bar
    %2do compás:
    \NOTes\hu f\hp\en\leftrepeat
    %3er compás
    \Notes\zcharnote{n}{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \huge{\A\bfseries\large 2}}\isluru0k\qu e\qu d\qu e\tslur0j\qu d\en\rightrepeat
    %4to compás
    \NOTes\hu e\hp\en\leftrepeat
    %5to compás
    \Notes\zcharnote{n}{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \huge{\A\bfseries\large 3}}\islurd0d\qu d\qu c\qu d\tslur0c\qu c\en\rightrepeat
    %6to compás
    \NOTes\hu d\hp\en
    %\setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Comment: AutoSolved then :)

Comment: The solution was given by Peters, thanks!!!